# Maven can't change the library set by default

Tags: java, maven

I have this problem when creating a maven project. I can't change the JRE library from J2SE-1.5 to Java-S.E 1.6 or 1.7 without errors. (and even with the J2SE-1.5, I have a warning)

I know that it's set by default, so I changed the maven compiler `plugin.pom` file but I still get the same error.

Here is what i modified in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.1</version>
           <configuration>
             <source>1.6</source>
             <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: What errors and warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the java version in your pom.xml is not good enough. You need to have the environment variable JAVA_HOME set to the version you intend to use. Maven uses this variable to build your project, so JAVA_HOME and the compiler plugin version must match.